# strchr() как она работает?

Tags: g++, c++, linux

я знаю, что эту функцию можно использовать в условиях, но как она работает на самом деле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Функция strchr() возвращает указатель на местонахождение первого совпадения с символом c в строке s ... а если символ не найден, то возвращают NULL.

Вот и все.

```
char *numbers = "01233210";
char *three = strchr(numbers, '3');

// three = &numbers[3];
```

Answer (score 11):

Если вас интересует реализация strchr, то в общих чертах она такая:

```
char* strchr(const char* str, int c) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] && str[i] != c) ++i;
    return c == str[i] ? (char*)str + i : NULL;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, огромное.

Comment: @Илья Михневич, обратите внимание, что strchr (str,0) вернет адрес завершающего строку нуля, а не NULL (хотя по определению строки **не содержат** двоичных нулей (!)).

-

Не знаю, это концептуальная ошибка разработчиков библиотеки или в таком поведении есть глубокий смысл.

Comment: 1. Строк в C нет, а char -- подмножество int. 2. Смысл есть. Можно дописать в конец строки.

Comment: Смысл очень простой -- при помощи strchr можно, в том числе, искать '\0' в массиве символов.

Comment: Нет строк, а есть массивы 8-разрядных целых, завершающиеся нулем. 

Это верно, хотя по простому говорят *строка*. Найти конец строки - strlen(), дописать в конец - strcat().

Искать '\0' логичней memchr() (хотя надо знать длину).

-

IMHO поиск конца через strchr() это извращенная логика, провоцирует логические ошибки (особенно если представить, что правишь чужую программу).

Answer (score 0):

```
char* strchr(const char* str, int c) {
int i = 0;
while ((str[i] != '\0') && (str[i] != c)) i++;
return str[i] == '\0' ? NULL : str[i];
}
```

Comment: В реальных реализациях она скорее [такая](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strchr.c) (а это код [strchrnul()](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strchrnul.c)) / Как видите, чтение памяти не по байтам, а словами

Answer (score -1):

не уходи в сторону и отнесись к функции просто как она есть, а именно 
 Обработка строк ----strchr - найти в строке первое вхождение символа с.
Определение:
char *strchr(s,n)
char* s;
int n;
не хотелось бы загромождать примерами но, если надо, пиши